# What is the best way to monitor stacks on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cloudformation, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently working on projects with Laravel/PHP that I manage with AWS.

I deploy several instances thanks to the CloudFormation service. So i have a lot of LogsGroups.

If I have an error in these LogsGroups, I have to manually search for the error logs.

So, my need is :

When I have an error API or PH message in one of my LogsGroups, like this:

```
[2021-11-24T13:03:48.075879+00:00] technical.ERROR: TYPE: Trzproject\Trzutils\Exceptions\InvalidJWTException   
MESSAGE: Provided JWT has since expired, as defined by the "exp" claim   
FILE: /var/task/vendor/trzproject/trzcore/src/Trzutils/JWT/JWTService.php   LINE: 64   TRACE:  stack trace disabled ____________________________________________________________________
```

I want to be alerted with a message (slack, mail, whatever) that tells me in which LogGroup is the error.

I can’t create a LogInsight query because I have a lot of clients and, LogInsight does not allow to make query on a very large amount of LogsGroups.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Edit : something like this ; https://theithollow.com/2017/12/11/use-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-metric-filters-send-alerts/

but without create x alarms for x logGroups

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand well what are your points. Are you going to catch any specific error messages in Cloudwatch? Or are you going to catch if someone failed login many times?

Comment: @shimo thank's for you'r message :)

My wish: I want to be alerted if one of my CloudFormation stacks set an error message in the LogsGroups of my all lambda.

Comment: How a CloudFormation stack can send any message? When it fails deploments or updates?

Comment: @Marcin

I edit my post, i just want to say : If i have a error api message on one of my LogsGroups, i want to be notified

something like this ; https://theithollow.com/2017/12/11/use-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-metric-filters-send-alerts/

but without create x alarms for x logGroups

Comment: @Mitsukk It has nothing to do with CloudFormation, you have to implement a custom solution for that.

Comment: @Marcin , it's a good solution to do this : https://towardsaws.com/aws-cloudwatch-error-alerts-450e7017198d

Cloudwatch Logs -> trigger Lambda when specifics message -> publish error message from cloudwatch to a SNS Topic

Thank's in advance

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171078/how-to-send-alert-based-on-log-message-on-cloudwatch) describes a very common pattern to do this. Create a metric filter, create a metric alarm, send the alarm to an SNS topic, and then subscribe to the topic by email, push to Slack (see [this application](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/641494176294/aws-sns-to-slack-publisher)), or something else.

Comment: @hephalump thank's for you'r response

This solution it's not good :( because i must to create X Alarm for each Metric FIlter (wer can create one Metric Filter for X LogsGroups ?)

Comment: Another pattern is to stream all your logs to [AWS OpenSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/) and then use the built-in alerting services instead of SNS (or sent the alerts to SNS). Your only options are to either work with an existing pattern to solve your problem, or build a custom solution.

Comment: @hephalump thank's again, I’ve never used OpenSearch and I don’t know how it works. Finaly, this option doesn't work : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/mt/get-notified-specific-lambda-function-error-patterns-using-cloudwatch/ ( Cloudwatch Logs -> trigger Lambda when specifics message -> publish error message to a SNS Topic ) because solution need to specify only ONE LogGroups :(.

I really don’t know how to fulfill my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this and it's a solution to my needs

I created a Lambda that is triggered by CloudWatch Logs. I’ve combined the log groups I want to monitor with CloudWatch Logs as well as a pattern to retrieve only certain messages.

serverless.yml

```
functions:
  persistLogMessage:
    handler: lambda/PersistLogMessage.php
    timeout: 899 # 14min 59s
    events:
      - cloudwatchLog:
          logGroup: 'MyLogsGroup01'
          filter: '?ERROR ?WARN ?5xx'
      - cloudwatchLog:
          logGroup: 'MyLogsGroup02'
          filter: '?ERROR ?WARN ?5xx'
      ...
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:layer:php-73:1
    role: PersistLogMessageRole
    ...
    resources:
    Conditions:
      Resources:
    #
    PersistLogMessageRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: ${opt:stage}-${opt:client}-PersistLogMessageRole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: PersistLogMessagePolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: "Allow"
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                    - logs:PutRetentionPolicy
                    - logs:DescribeLogStreams
                    - logs:DescribeLogGroups
                  Resource: "*"
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - sns:Publish
                  Resource:
                    - "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-3:<account_id>:SnsTopic"
```

My Lambda:

```
public function __invoke(array $events): void
{
    $data = $events['awslogs']['data'];
    $this->logger->info('events', $events);
    $dataDecoded = base64_decode($data);
    $logMessage = zlib_decode($dataDecoded);
    /** @var stdClass $stdClassLogMessage */
    $stdClassLogMessage = json_decode($logMessage);
    dump($stdClassLogMessage);

    $params = [
        'Message' => $stdClassLogMessage->logEvents[0]->message,
        'TopicArn' => 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-3:<account_id>:SnsTopic'
    ];

    $this->snsClient->publish($params);
}
```

[image]